# Sequelize schema for PostgreSQL: How to accurately define a schema in a model?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, schema, sequelize.js, database-schema

I searched throughout the net and have not been able to determine how to add a schema to this sequelize model below. The following code does not kick back errors, however when I inspect the postgres DB, the only schema is the default one for public.

```
// The model definition is done in /path/to/models/project.js
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {
  return sequelize.define("project", {
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    description: DataTypes.TEXT,
  },
    define: {
        schema: "prefix"
    },
    classMethods: {
      method1: function() {},
      method2: function() {}
  },
    instanceMethods: {
      method3: function() {}
  })
```

How should the script be revised to accurately define a schema?

**EDIT**

In my case, the final answer was

```
 database_name.sequelize.createSchema('prefix').then(() => {...});
```

in my ./models/index.js file the database object is as follows:

```
database_name = {
    Sequelize: Sequelize,
    sequelize: sq,
    table_1: sq.import(__dirname + '/file_folder')
 };

module.exports = database_name;
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Your model definition should look as follows

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

    return sequelize.define("project", {
        name: DataTypes.STRING,
        description: DataTypes.TEXT,
    }, {
        schema: 'prefix',
        classMethods: {
            method1: function() {},
            method2: function() {}
        },
        instanceMethods: {
            method3: function() {}
        }
    }
}
```

According to the documentation of [`options`](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#definemodelname-attributes-options-model) object in `sequelize.define` method, it can have attribute called `schema`.

**EDIT** - Creating schema programatically

In order to create a new schema (only for PostgreSQL!), you can use the [**`sequelize.createSchema()`**](http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/api/sequelize/#createschemaschema-options-promise) method:

```
sequelize.createSchema('prefix').then(() => {
    // new schema is created
});
```

Above creates given SQL

```sql
CREATE SCHEMA prefix;
```

In order to use this schema in model definitions, you need to create the schema before synchronising any model into the database - it could be run before `sequelize.sync()` or, if you use migrations, as a first migration file.

Comment: This does not work. It kicks back "schema does not exist"

Comment: Do you use `sequelize.sync()` to synchronize the database or you use migrations?

Comment: Because you need to create a schema before defining models in it

Comment: I don't use migrations yet. Yes I use sequelize.sync() to synchronize the DB. Can I define it programmatically without going doing it through the CLI?

Comment: I have edited the answer to include the schema creation part

Comment: In my specific case, I had preformed the following: database_name.sequelize.createSchema('prefix').then(() => {...}); This was based on how I define the database in the index.js file.

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to define the schema in the create table migration file like so:

```
queryInterface.createTable(
  'nameOfTheNewTable',
  {
    id: {
      type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
      primaryKey: true,
      autoIncrement: true
    },
    createdAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE
    },
    updatedAt: {
      type: Sequelize.DATE
    },
    attr1: Sequelize.STRING,
    attr2: Sequelize.INTEGER,
    attr3: {
      type: Sequelize.BOOLEAN,
      defaultValue: false,
      allowNull: false
    },
    //foreign key usage
    attr4: {
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER,
        references: {
            model: 'another_table_name',
            key: 'id'
        },
        onUpdate: 'cascade',
        onDelete: 'cascade'
    }
  },
  {
    engine: 'MYISAM',                     // default: 'InnoDB'
    charset: 'latin1',                    // default: null
    schema: 'prefix'                      // default: public, PostgreSQL only.
  }
```

Comment: This will change the default schema. The question is specific to changing the schema for a specific model.

Answer (score 1):

This code works with "sequelize": "^4.23.2","pg": "^7.4.0", "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",

```
const User = sequelize.define('people', {
        uuid: {
            type: Sequelize.UUID,
            defaultValue: Sequelize.UUIDV1,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        username: Sequelize.STRING,
        email: Sequelize.STRING,
        birthday: Sequelize.DATE
    }, {
            schema: 'public',
        });

    sequelize.sync()
        .then(() => User.create({
            username: 'MartialDoane',
            email: 'martial-doane@gmail.com',
            birthday: new Date(1977, 6, 11)
        }))
        .then(jane => {
            console.log(jane.toJSON());

            res.send(jane);
            res.status(200);
        });
```

That will create the table in schema public and not my default schema.

Comment: this is not working for me.The DB have table under schema called public so 
I have added {schema: 'public'} in the model
but the find query returns empty object

Answer (score 0):

Try this to create schema Programmatically before creating models.

Add this code immediately after import statements.

Replace "some_schema" with Your "Schema Name"

file: models/index.js

1.JavaScript Implementation

```js
 (async function () {
  await sequelize.showAllSchemas({ logging: false }).then(async (data) => {
        if (!data.includes('some_schema')) {
         await sequelize.createSchema('some_schema');
        }
        if (!data.includes('some_schema2')) {
         await sequelize.createSchema('some_schema2');
       }
  });
}());
```

Tip: 1st time npm start will throw error that schema doesnt exist ,close npm terminal and npm start again ,it will work without any error on 2nd time,because of async nature.

2.Typescript Implementation :

```js
(async function () {
  const allSchema: Array<string> = await sequelize
    .showAllSchemas({ logging: false })
    .then((data) => data.map((ele) => ele.toString()));
  if (!allSchema.includes('some_schema')) {
    await sequelize.createSchema('some_schema', { logging: false });
  }
})();
```